# Can direct be used correctly as an adverb, and if so how is it different from directly?

Tags: adverbs

I read this on the web:

> "International students can apply direct to the University of Western Sydney."

How can "direct" which is a verb acts as an adverb? Is it possible ?  Although I think it might be a noun here.

If it is an adverb then what is the difference between it and "directly" ?

Comment: **direct** is more direct than **directly**.  It's like saying "go *straight* to prison".

Comment: You may want to consult a dictionary such as [this one](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/direct_3).

Comment: Direct can work as a verb, adjective or adverb. It has several meanings for each of them. Here is a list: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/direct

Comment: In general, not all adverbs end in *-ly*. To me, there's no difference in meaning between *direct* &  *directly* used as an  adjective.

Comment: Thank you all so much, I had consulted Merriam Webster dictionary but all definations are only about "direct" as a verb , nothing else.

Comment: Actually there are definitions of “direct” as adverb as well. I think this question can be answered using only a dictionary, so I'm not sure why it hasn't been closed/deleted/whatever.

Comment: This doesn't sound correct to my American English ear. However I have heard British people use the word "direct" as an adverb, like you have in your quote. Personally, I would say "directly"

Answer (score -1):

English is a Germanic language and is closely related to Frisian, Dutch and German.

We can correctly guess that most adjectives will function as adverbs without any modification--because that's how adjectives work in all four of these languages.